# Как реализовать мехпнизм сверки с базой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код который просто сверяет значение в переменной с значениеми в json, когда находит совпадение выводит нужную информацию. Но у меня не получаеться реализовать механизм который бы выводил сообщение что результатов поиска нет.

Вместо этого функция выводит что результатов нет несколько тысяч раз . То есть каждый раз когда происходит сверка и нет совпадений с json выводит сообщение.

Как можно решить проблемму ?

Вот мой код :

```js
function Zvalue(value_test) {
  $.each(allNam, function(key, val) {
    if (value_test == value['actNam']) {

      setTimeout(function() {

        gomasege(value['varNam'])
      }, 600);
    } else if (value_test !== value['actNam']) {
      console.log("нет совпадений")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: А что за переменная value[] ? Она нигде в коде не объявлена... Или это опечатка именно в примере и должен быть val[]

Comment: @ Mike, опечатка спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить вроблему с помощью флага:

```
    function Zvalue(value_test) {
      var anyMatches = false;

      $.each(allNam, function(key, val) {
        if (value_test == val['actNam']) {
          anyMatches = true;

          setTimeout(function() {
              gomasege(val['varNam']);
          }, 600);
        }
      });

      if (!anyMatches)
          console.log("нет совпадений");
    }
```

**OffTop**
Маленькая штука для холивара. Если `allNam` достаточно большой, лучше `$.each` заменить на цикл `for ()`, ибо `$.each()` в `jQuery` не слишком хорошо реализован.